# Why are dynamic imports unexpectedly coupled between tests when using mock-fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic-import, mock-fs

I'm trying to use `mock-fs` to unit test code which uses [ES6 dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

There seems to be an unexpected coupling between tests when I'm using dynamic imports, even though I call `restore()` after each test. It appears as though `fs.readFile()` behaves as expected between tests (no coupling), but `await import()` has coupling (it returns the result from the previous test).

I've created a minimal Jest test case that reproduces the issue. The tests pass individually, but not when run together. I notice that if I change the `directory` value so it's different between each test, then they pass together.

Can you help me understand why this doesn't work, whether it's a bug, and what I should do here?

```js
import path from 'path';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import mockFs from 'mock-fs';

const fsMockModules = {
  node_modules: mockFs.load(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')),
};

describe('Reproduce dynamic import coupling between tests', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    mockFs.restore();
  });
  it('first test', async () => {
    const directory = 'some/path';
    mockFs({
      ...fsMockModules,
      [directory]: {
        'index.js': ``,
      },
    });
    await import(path.resolve(`${directory}/index.js`));
    //not testing anything here, just illustrating the coupling for next test
  });
  it('second tests works in isolation but not together with first test', async () => {
    const directory = 'some/path';
    mockFs({
      ...fsMockModules,
      [directory]: {
        'index.js': `export {default as migrator} from './migrator.js';`,
        'migrator.js':
          'export default (payload) => ({...payload, xyz: 123});',
      },
    });
    const indexFile = await fs.readFile(`${directory}/index.js`, 'utf-8');
    expect(indexFile.includes('export {default as migrator}')).toBe(true);
    const migrations = await import(path.resolve(`${directory}/index.js`));
    expect(typeof migrations.migrator).toBe('function');
  });
});
```